# Unset a specific element from an array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [nid] => 1
            [language] => EN
            [uid] => 1
            [tid] => page
            [title] => Welcome
            [body] => 
Comming Soon.


            [date_post] => 2014-02-18 08:27:56
            [enable] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [nid] => 2
            [language] => EN
            [uid] => 1
            [tid] => page
            [title] => Our Stuff
            [body] => 
Comming Soon.

            [date_post] => 2014-02-18 08:27:56
            [enable] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [nid] => 3
            [language] => EN
            [uid] => 1
            [tid] => page
            [title] => Partners
            [body] => 
Comming Soon.


            [date_post] => 2014-02-18 08:27:56
            [enable] => 1
        )
```

And so on... What i would like to do i unset the element how has the title `Partners` for example, so I tried this :

```
unset($pages[array_search('Partners',$pages)]);
```

But it remove the first element from the table, so how can i unset the specific element ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`array_search()` only searches elements in the main array.  Those elements are themselves arrays, so it returns `false`.  You need to to iterate through each sub array either with an array function or a loop:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if($value['title'] == 'Partners') {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if it explained what was doing and why the example doesn't work and this does.

Comment: @SteveBuzonas: Was headed out, added.

Comment: @steffen: Sorry, rushed example, deleted.

Answer (score 4):

It's because `array_search` searches your array for the string 'Partners'. But as your array only contains 3 arrays, no entry is found. `array_search` will result `false` which evaluates to `0`. That's why the first key is removed.

You need to search inside each array (`foreach ($myarray as $array) { ... }`). And you also **must** check the return value:

```
$value = array_search(...);
if ($value !== false) {
    // do unset
}
```

Solution with [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
// Remove all arrays having 'title' => 'Partners'
$arr = array_filter($arr, function($e) { return $e['title'] != 'Partners'; });

// Remove all arrays containing a value 'Partners'
$arr = array_filter($arr, function($e) { return array_search('Partners', $e) === false; });
```